# How to specify in supabase a field should only have default value?

Tags: supabase, row-level-security

I'm making a basic chat app using supabase.
I've figured out how to make it so users can only create/edit their profile and send messages from their profile using RLS, by checking if their `id` matches with the `auth.id`.

The problem I'm facing is, that I don't want users to be able to insert messages with wrong creation dates.
If no date is specified the default value is correct. But currently there is no check for the creation date.
Can I specify, that the creation date field has to be sent empty?
Is there maybe a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is you can override the `created_at` field with the current server timestamp using triggers.

Code not verified, so you might have to make some small adjustments, but the idea is this:

```sql
create extension if not exists moddatetime schema extensions;

-- assuming the table name is "messages", and a timestamp column "created_at"
-- this trigger will set the "created_at" column to the current timestamp for every insert
create trigger
  handle_created_at before insert
on messages
for each row execute
  procedure moddatetime(created_at);
```